# ¿Por qué tengo este error a la hora de subir una imagen con php al servidor?

Tags: php, html5

Estoy creando una página para que suba imágenes al servidor, este es mi index:

```js
(function() {
  "use strict";

  $(".input-file").each(function() {
    var $input = $(this),
        $label = $input.next(".js-labelFile"),
        labelVal = $label.html();

    $input.on("change", function(element) {
      var fileName = "";
      if (element.target.value) fileName = element.target.value.split("\\").pop();
      fileName ? $label.addClass("has-file").find(".js-fileName").html(fileName) : $label.removeClass("has-file").html(labelVal);

    });
  });
})();
```

```css
/* Etiquetas */

html, body {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 auto;
}
body {
  background-color:white;
  font-family: 'Open Sans','Helvetica Neue',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
}

h1, h3 {
  color:black;
}


/* Formulario */

.input-file {
  width: 0.1px;
  height: 0.1px;
  opacity: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
}
.input-file + .js-labelFile {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding: 0 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.input-file + .js-labelFile .icon:before {
  content: "\f093";
}
.input-file + .js-labelFile.has-file .icon:before {
  content: "\f00c";
  color: #5AAC7B;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="author" content="Diesan Romero">
  <meta name="description" content="Sube tus imagenes de manera temporal">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mdbootstrap/4.5.0/css/mdb.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="src/styles.css">
  <title>Imágenes Momentaneas</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row justify-content-center mt-5">
      <h1><span>Imágenes Momentáneas</span></h1>
    </div>
    <div class="row justify-content-center mt-4">
      <form action="data.php" method="post"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div class="form">
          <h3 class="row justify-content-center mt-5">Seleccione el tiempo en minutos que estará su imagen en línea</h3>
          <div class="row justify-content-center mt-1">
            <div class="btn-group" role="group">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning">1</button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning">5</button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning">15</button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning">30</button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning">60</button>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row justify-content-center mt-5">
            <input type="file" name="imagen" id="imagen" class="input-file">
            <label for="imagen" class="btn btn-lg btn-outline-red js-labelFile">
              <i class="icon fa fa-check"></i>
              <span class="js-fileName">Elija la imagen a subir</span>
            </label>
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-red" value="Subir Imagen">
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
    <div class="row justify-content-center mt-2">
      <div class="col-4">
        <div class="alert alert-success invisible" role="alert">
          La imagen ha sido cargada correctamente, ahora debe subirla.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.13.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mdbootstrap/4.5.0/js/mdb.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="src/main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

y acá tengo el php que recogerá los datos de la imagen:

```
<?php
// Informacion de la imagen
  $nombre = $_FILES['imagen']['name'];
  $tipo = $_FILES['imagen']['type'];
  $tamano = $_FILES['imagen']['size'];

  //Ruta de la carpeta destino en servidor
  $destino = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/imagenes/uploads';

  //Envia la imagen del directorio temporar al servidor
  move_uploaded_file($_FILES['imagen']['tmp_name'], $destino.$nombre);
?>
```

el problema acá es que cuando subo la imagen, que la envío al servidor me salen estos dos errores:

> Warning: move_uploaded_file(C:/xampp/htdocs/imagenes/uploads2.JPG):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\imagenes-momentaneas\data.php on line 11
>
> Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move
>   'C:\xampp\tmp\php5078.tmp' to 'C:/xampp/htdocs/imagenes/uploads2.JPG'
>   in C:\xampp\htdocs\imagenes-momentaneas\data.php on line 11

no se mucho php, y no logro aún comprender cuál es el problema acá.

Comment: tengo duda por que le concatenas al final la variable $nombre?

Comment: no solo debería ser destino y ya sin la variable $nombre

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te muestra las advertencias porque no existe la carpeta, y al no existir la carpeta no puede crear el archivo, para que no pase eso podemos validar que existan, si no existen las creamos con [`mkdir`](https://secure.php.net/manual/es/function.mkdir.php) y luego guardamos el archivo. También te sugiero utilizar la [constante](https://secure.php.net/manual/es/dir.constants.php) de PHP `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` para que no dependas del sistema operativo

```
<?php
// Informacion de la imagen
  $nombre = $_FILES['imagen']['name'];
  $tipo = $_FILES['imagen']['type'];
  $tamano = $_FILES['imagen']['size'];

  //Ruta de la carpeta destino en servidor
  $carpetaImagenes = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'imagenes';
  if (!is_dir($carpetaImagenes)) {
      mkdir($carpetaImagenes, 0775);
  }
  if (!is_writable($carpetaImagenes)) {
      chmod($carpetaImagenes, 0775);
  }

  $carpetaUploads = $carpetaImagenes.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'uploads';
  if (!is_dir($carpetaUploads)) {
      mkdir($carpetaUploads, 0775);
  }
  if (!is_writable($carpetaUploads)) {
      chmod($carpetaUploads, 0775);
  }

  // Envia la imagen del directorio temporar al servidor
  move_uploaded_file($_FILES['imagen']['tmp_name'], $carpetaUploads.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$nombre);
?>
```

Comment: No me crea la carpeta ni mucho menos me agrega el archivo.

Comment: No me crea la carpeta ni mucho menos me agrega el archivo.

Comment: @DiesanRomero edité mi respuesta, avisame si te marca algún error

Comment: No ocurrió nada, ni un error ni nada. Si quieres te doy acceso a mi computadora por teamviewer para ver si por fin puedo arreglar ese problema.

Comment: Ahí lo veo sin falta.

Answer (score 1):

La idea es moverlo a una ubicación que por el momento será temporal; entonces debería quedar así

```
<?php
// Informacion de la imagen
  $nombre = $_FILES['imagen']['name'];
  $tipo = $_FILES['imagen']['type'];
  $tamano = $_FILES['imagen']['size'];

  //Ruta de la carpeta destino en servidor
  $destino = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/imagenes/uploads/';

  //Envia la imagen del directorio temporar al servidor
  move_uploaded_file($_FILES['imagen']['tmp_name'], $destino);
?>
```

Es decir dentro de la función no sería necesario mandarle el valor $nombre

Comment: sigo teniendo el mismo problema

Answer (score 1):

Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move 'C:\xampp\tmp\php5078.tmp' to 'C:/xampp/htdocs/imagenes/**uploads2.JPG**'

te falta un slash entre uploads y nombre, salta el error al no poder escribir en /imagenes

asimismo fijate que /imagenes/uploads tenga permisos de escritura para el php/apache

sino el error saltará nuevamente

Comment: Uso Xampp, dónde puedo ver y modificar los permisos?

Comment: desde el explorador de windows vas a la carpeta y boton derecho propiedades pestaña seguridad, editar, agregar, y pones el usuario bajo el que corre el apache. por lo general ya tiene permisos de escritura pero puede ser un caso especial. asegurate que la carpeta existe tal vez sea eso y no los permisos

Comment: Intento ver las variables de entorno del servidor para ver el usuario con este codigo `<?php

$user = getenv('APACHE_RUN_USER');
$group = getenv('APACHE_RUN_GROUP');
echo $user.":";
echo $group."";

?>
` pero no logro nada.

Comment: con el administrador de tareas (taskmanager) en la pestaña detalles te da una lista de procesos y el usuario bajo el que corre